# Toggle with two functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to set up a checkbox, that when given a true value will load information, and when false unload that information. Currently I have two buttons with these functions, but wish to have a quick access toggle. I can't seem to figure out how to have if true/false for a toggle function however.

HTML - hardcoded button for loading.

```
<span class="label" data-bind="css: {click: function () {$root.loadLayerSource(Source, ReadableName, Type, URL, Description)}">Load</span>
```

JS:

```
//Disable layers if checkbox is false
this.disableLayer = function (layerId, type) {
   //            
}

// .....

//Enable layers if checkbox is true
this.loadLayerSource = function (source, name, type, url, description){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> I don't want to show or hide HTML elements, rather I need to execute two different functions loadLayerSource or disableLayer

If there's no showing/hiding and it's purely a matter of calling functions, then bind the checkbox to a boolean observable via the `checked` binding and subscribe to it:

```js
var vm = {
  showing: ko.observable(false),
  output: ko.observableArray()
};
vm.showing.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    doThis();
  } else {
    doThat();
  }
});
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);

function doThis() {
  vm.output.push("Doing 'this' because value was true");
}

function doThat() {
  vm.output.push("Doing 'that' because value was false");
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showing">
  Show
</label>
<div data-bind="foreach: output">
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

Original answer when I thought you were mostly showing/hiding stuff, with optional subscription as well:

Bind the checkbox to a boolean observable via the `checked` binding, then show/hide the other information based on the value of that observable.

```js
var vm = {
  showing: ko.observable(false)
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showing">
  Show
</label>
<div data-bind="visible: showing">This is visible when showing</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

If you need to kick off some further process when the observable changes, you can do that by subscribing to it.

```js
var vm = {
  showing: ko.observable(false),
  loading: ko.observable(false),
  data: ko.observable(null),
  loadData: function() {
    this.loading(true);
    setTimeout(function() {
      vm.loading(false);
      vm.data("The data is ready now");
    }, 500);
  }
};
vm.showing.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  if (newValue && !vm.data()) {
    vm.loadData();
  }
});
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showing">
  Show
</label>
<div data-bind="visible: showing">
  <div data-bind="visible: loading">Loading...</div>
  <div data-bind="visible: data, text: data"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't want to show or hide HTML elements, rather I need to execute two different functions loadLayerSource or disableLayer

Comment: @KeiranLovett: Ah. Then it's just a `subscribe`, I'll update.

Comment: Good solution. Alternatively, a *writable* `computed` observable could also work. It's akin to having a c# property that has additional logic in the `set`ter.

Comment: @KeiranLovett: I've added just the simple `subscribe` to the top of the answer.